# Ignore outliers in ggplot2 boxplot + faceting + "free" options

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet, boxplot, outliers

How can I adjust my Y axis in order to ignore outliers, like in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5677885/ignore-outliers-in-ggplot2-boxplot), but in a more challenging case where I have 4 boxplots and a "free faceting" layout?

> p <- ggplot(molten.DF,aes(x=class,y=SOC,fill=class)) + 
>     geom_boxplot() + 
>     facet_grid(layer~.,scales="free",space="free")

As you can see on my figure, considering outliers in the Y axis range make the boxes more difficult to read. No importance if some outliers are still visible in the result, but I would like to really focus on the boxes!

[image: boxplot with free scale, all outliers are (unfortuately) visibles]

Comment: If you post a reproducible example for us to work with it becomes much easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 2):

It obviously depends on what you consider an outlier. If it's possible for you to calculate it, you can set your `ylim` at this value an let those points out of the chart.

For example, if you assume that the upper and lower limits are Q3 + 1.5 IQR and Q1 - 1.5 IQR, and this is the way boxplots usually have its outliers limit calculated, you would have:

```
upper.fence <- quantile(x)[4] + 1.5*IQR(x)
lower.fence <- quantile(x)[2] - 1.5*IQR(x)
```

Then you can use these limits as the `y` range of values:

```
my.ggplot + coord_cartesian(ylim=c(lower.fence, upper.fence))
```

The procedure you use to get your upper and lower limits can change, but the use of the limits is the same.

Comment: I think it's safe to assume OP wants outliers as defined by ggplot: http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/geom_boxplot.html (Details section). Also, the `ylim` approach only works for a single boxplot, since outliers of some boxplots will be inside the fence of others.