# Remove outliers fully from multiple boxplots made with ggplot2 in R and display the boxplots in expanded format

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot, outliers

I have some data [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/4wrqfcvr0tngimt/data.txt) [in a .txt file] which I read into a data frame df,

```
df <- read.table("data.txt", header=T,sep="\t")
```

I remove the negative values in the column `x` (since I need only positive values) of the `df` using the following code,

```
yp <- subset(df, x>0)
```

Now I want plot multiple box plots in the same layer. I first melt the data frame `df`, and the plot which results contains several outliers as shown below.

```
# Melting data frame df    
df_mlt <-melt(df, id=names(df)[1])
    # plotting the boxplots
    plt_wool <- ggplot(subset(df_mlt, value > 0), aes(x=ID1,y=value)) + 
      geom_boxplot(aes(color=factor(ID1))) +
      scale_y_log10(breaks = trans_breaks("log10", function(x) 10^x), labels = trans_format("log10", math_format(10^.x))) +    
      theme_bw() +
      theme(legend.text=element_text(size=14), legend.title=element_text(size=14))+
      theme(axis.text=element_text(size=20)) +
      theme(axis.title=element_text(size=20,face="bold")) +
      labs(x = "x", y = "y",colour="legend" ) +
      annotation_logticks(sides = "rl") +
      theme(panel.grid.minor = element_blank()) +
      guides(title.hjust=0.5) +
      theme(plot.margin=unit(c(0,1,0,0),"mm")) 
    plt_wool
```

[image: Boxplot with outliers]

Now I need to have a plot without any outliers, so to do this first I compute the lower and upper bound whiskers I use the following code as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5677885/ignore-outliers-in-ggplot2-boxplot),

```
sts <- boxplot.stats(yp$x)$stats
```

To remove the outlier I add the upper and lower whisker limits as below,

```
p1 = plt_wool + coord_cartesian(ylim = c(sts*1.05,sts/1.05))
```

The resulting plot is shown below, while the above line of code correctly removes most of the top outliers all the bottom outliers still remain. Could someone please suggest how to remove all the outlier completely from this plot, Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Based on suggestions by @Sven Hohenstein, @Roland and @lukeA I have solved the problem for displaying multiple boxplots in expanded form without outliers.

First plot the box plots without outliers by using `outlier.colour=NA` in `geom_boxplot()`

```
plt_wool <- ggplot(subset(df_mlt, value > 0), aes(x=ID1,y=value)) + 
  geom_boxplot(aes(color=factor(ID1)),outlier.colour = NA) +
  scale_y_log10(breaks = trans_breaks("log10", function(x) 10^x), labels = trans_format("log10", math_format(10^.x))) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(legend.text=element_text(size=14), legend.title=element_text(size=14))+
  theme(axis.text=element_text(size=20)) +
  theme(axis.title=element_text(size=20,face="bold")) +
  labs(x = "x", y = "y",colour="legend" ) +
  annotation_logticks(sides = "rl") +
  theme(panel.grid.minor = element_blank()) +
  guides(title.hjust=0.5) +
  theme(plot.margin=unit(c(0,1,0,0),"mm"))
```

Then compute the lower, upper whiskers using `boxplot.stats()` as the code below. Since I only take into account positive values, I choose them using the condition in the `subset()`.

```
yp <- subset(df, x>0)             # Choosing only +ve values in col x
sts <- boxplot.stats(yp$x)$stats  # Compute lower and upper whisker limits
```

Now to achieve full expanded view of the multiple boxplots, it is useful to modify the y-axis limit of the plot inside `coord_cartesian()` function as below,

```
p1 = plt_wool + coord_cartesian(ylim = c(sts[2]/2,max(sts)*1.05))
```

**Note:**  The limits of y should be adjusted according to the specific case. In this case I have chosen half of lower whisker limit for ymin.

The resulting plot is below,

[image]

Comment: much distraction in this otherwise nice answer

Comment: Great answer. Such a simple fix using outlier.colour = NA

Answer (score 25):

A minimal reproducible example:

```
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(cyl), mpg))
p + geom_boxplot()
```

Not plotting outliers:

```
p + geom_boxplot(outlier.shape=NA)
#Warning message:
#Removed 3 rows containing missing values (geom_point).
```

(I prefer to get this warning, because a year from now with a long script it would remind me that I did something special there. If you want to avoid it use Sven's solution.)

Comment: This is a good way, however, the Y-limitation is not change and therefore the figure is not looks well with large white space in the top

Answer (score 4):

You can make the outliers invisible with the argument `outlier.colour = NA`:

```
geom_boxplot(aes(color = factor(ID1)), outlier.colour = NA)
```

Comment: To Sven Hohenstein and @Roland The problem with removing the outliers in such a way here is that, the boxes in the boxplot still remains squished. What I would like to have is the boxes in the boxplot in an expanded form, like the one shown in the image 2 of my question but without the outliers though.

Comment: I solved the issue (see above answer) with regards to expanding the boxplot after removal of the outliers.

Answer (score 4):

Another way to exclude outliers is to calculate them then set the y-limit on what you consider an outlier.

For example, if your upper and lower limits are `Q3 + 1.5 IQR`  and `Q1 - 1.5 IQR`, then you may use:

```
upper.limit <- quantile(x)[4] + 1.5*IQR(x)
lower.limit <- quantile(x)[2] - 1.5*IQR(x)
```

Then put limits on the y-axis range:

```
ggplot + coord_cartesian(ylim=c(lower.limit, upper.limit))
```

Comment: as the OP included in their question this solution is not suitable for the problem

Answer (score 3):

```
ggplot(df_mlt, aes(x = ID1, y = value)) + 
  geom_boxplot(outlier.size = NA) + 
  coord_cartesian(ylim = range(boxplot(df_mlt$value, plot=FALSE)$stats)*c(.9, 1.1))
```

Comment: This removes outliers in top and bottom but it ends up displaying a single boxplot. I need multiple boxplots though, I have solved this now, thanks.