# ggplot2 how to get rid of duplicate dots?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I made a trial where I compare 2 different conditions for multiple treatments. However, on the plot, some of the value have two points where they should only be one.

here is the code I used for my plot

```
ggplot(Bites, aes(x=Treatment, y=Biting, colour=Condition, fill=Condition))+
    geom_point(position=position_jitterdodge(dodge.width=0.7), size=2)+
    geom_boxplot(alpha=0.5, position= position_dodge(width=0.8), fatten=NULL)+
    stat_summary(fun.y= mean, geom="errorbar", aes(ymax=..y.., ymin=..y..),
        width=0.65, size= 1.5, linetype= "solid", position = position_dodge(width=0.7))+
    xlab("Treatment") +
    ylab("Bites")+
    labs(Color ="Condition")+   
    theme_classic()
```

[image: ggplot graph]

Here are part of the data I used.

```
   Biting Treatment Condition
1       0         A         X
2       0         A         X
3       0         A         X
4       0         A         X
5       0         A         X
6       0         A         X
7       0         A         X
8       0         A         X
9       1         A         X
10      1         A         X
11      1         A         X
12      2         A         X
13      4         A         X
14      7         A         X
15      9         A         X
```

I should only get one point in the graph for 4 bites, 7 bites and 9 bites; yet I get 2 dots (one red and one paler).

How can I get rid of the paler dots ?

Comment: Welcome to stack overlfow. Consider following this [guideline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) to post questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This duplicated dots are the outliers from `geom_boxplot()` (notice, how they are always centered on boxplot)

[image: Example plot]

Simply add `outlier.shape = NA` inside `geom_boxplot()` (as it was suggested under [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21533158/remove-outliers-fully-from-multiple-boxplots-made-with-ggplot2-in-r-and-display/21548689)) and then they won't appear.

[image: Solution plot]

Data:

```
Bites <- data.frame(Biting = sample(c(rep(0, 7), rep(1, 3), 2, 4, 7, 9)),
                    Treatment = c(rep("A", 7), rep("B", 7)),
                    Condition = rep(c("X", "Y"), 7))
```

Answer (score 0):

The lighter points are the outliers from the geom_boxplot call. Look up the option to suppress outliers on that call and you should be sweet.

ps - use dput() to share data frames in a stack overflow question to make it easy for others to assist.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I managed to get rid of them with the function outlier.color=0.

PS: I'll use dput(), next time, sorry it was my first post I didn't knew

Comment: We all had a first post once! Don’t forget to tick the best answer (RaV,s at this point) and upvote items that are helpful.