# Marking outliers on/off in ggplot as in the base package for shiny app

Tags: r, data-visualization, ggplot2

```
boxplot(as.formula(formulaText()),
        data = df,
        outline = input$outliers)
```

By selecting `outline = true/false`, outliers can be shown interactively in r shiny:

```
p<- ggplot(df, aes_string(x=input$variable1, y=input$variable)) +
  geom_boxplot() + coord_flip()
print(p)
```

Is there a flag or work around to achieve the same in the ggplot2 package?

Comment: As a code question, this would be a better fit on SO - see our [help/on-topic]

Comment: You can use `geom_boxplot(outlier.shape = NA)` to avoid showing outliers, so you should be be able to use `input$outliers` to assign either a shape (like the default, 19) or `NA`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ignore outliers in ggplot2 boxplot](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5677885/ignore-outliers-in-ggplot2-boxplot)