# How to resize the y-axis in boxplots without oultliers in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot, outliers, yaxis

I can make a simple boxplot in baseR : in this example the boxplot represents the counts number(n) explained by queries (query) :

```
boxplot(tmp$n ~ tmp$query)
```

[image]

Sometimes we don't want to show the outliers, the code is straightforward and it automatically resizes the y-axis.

```
boxplot(tmp$n ~ tmp$query, outline = FALSE)
```

[image]

However, in ggplot : WITH outliers

```
tmp %>% ggplot(aes(x = query, y = n)) + geom_boxplot()
```

[image]

Although the code does not show the outliers, the y-axis does not change. Any suggestion ?

```
tmp %>% ggplot(aes(x = query, y = n)) + geom_boxplot(outlier.shape = NA)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi. Possibly a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5677885/5193830) ?