# change y_limit via outlier.shape=NA in boxplot in R

Tags: r, boxplot, outliers

when plotting a boxplot in R, we can remove/hide outliers by `outlier.shape=NA`, but this does not change the limits of y-axis. so, if there is an outlier of size 1000, and the rest of the plot lies below 50, there will be a huge empty space in the plot, pushing the boxes to the lower part and make them look small.

Is there anyway to shrink the y-axis limits automatically?

Thanks

Comment: Can you add a reproducible example along with the code that you are using to generate the plot ?

Comment: subset your data to remove outliers before plotting?

Answer (score 0):

You can shrink the axis, x or y by specifying `xlim` or `ylim` with lower and upper limits inside the brackets in `ggplot2`

example with mtcars :

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = factor(am), y=mpg)) + 
geom_boxplot() + 
ylim(NA, 32) # case you want to change the upper limits (e.g.)
```

Furthermore, you may want to know how outlier are considered in ggplot. According how your data are distributed, you could replace the upper limit number in `ylim` with something like `quantile(mtcars$mpg, 0.95)` if you want to remove point after the 95th percentile without setting a value manually.

Answer (score 0):

The solution here works:
[Ignore outliers in ggplot2 boxplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5677885/ignore-outliers-in-ggplot2-boxplot)

coord_cartesian(ylim = ylim1*1.05)