# add interactivity to basic box plot r

Tags: r, ggplot2, graphics, boxplot

I'm trying to create a box plot without outliers

I have tried with ggplot's outlier.shape but the result was not satisfactory as it hides most part of the Whiskers because of the different range in Resolved_Hour column across priority. Tweaking the cartesian coordinates further elongates the Whisker's

```
a <- ggplot(data, aes(x=priority,y=Resolved_Hour,color = priority))+
  geom_boxplot(outlier.shape = NA)+
  coord_cartesian(ylim = quantile(data$Resolved_Hour,c(0.25,0.75),na.rm = T))

ggplotly(a)
```

Eg:

[image]

The basic box plot from graphics library helped me plot without outliers using **outline = F**

```
boxplot(Resolved_Hour ~ priority,data = data,horizontal=TRUE,axes=TRUE,outline=FALSE,col = "bisque")
```

But I couldn't add interactivity to this plot as

```
a <- boxplot(Resolved_Hour ~ priority,data = data,horizontal=TRUE,axes=TRUE,outline=FALSE,col = "bisque")

ggplotly(a)
```

It throws an error as

> Error in UseMethod("ggplotly", p) :
> no applicable method for 'ggplotly' applied to an object of class "list"

The plot is saved as a list as below:
[image]

Any help is highly appreciated :-) to resolve and plot a better box plot.
Thank you.

Comment: Couldn’t you just remove them from the dataset prior to plotting?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ignore outliers in ggplot2 boxplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5677885/ignore-outliers-in-ggplot2-boxplot)

Comment: In my opinion your issue is not related to ggplot2 vs. base boxplot but is a ggplotly issue instead, i.e. using `outlier.shape=NA` works fine for me in ggplot2 but is ignored by `ggplotly`.