# Why does ggplot geom_jitter plots extra values?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Why does my graph plot 3 extra black dots?

```
df <- tibble::tibble(
  ID = 1:52,
  Variable = c(rep("A",24),rep("B",28)),
  Variable2 = c(rep("1",11),rep("2",7),rep("3",6),rep("1",11),rep("2",11),rep("3",6) ),
  value = c(72,92,77,84,44,85,38,79,77,84,72,81,83,90,96,30,83,76,90,89,81,87,98,83,56,75,59,60,60,62,74,50,75,67,62,90,78,72,70,85,84,55,75,53,82,62,47,57,52,50,63,61)
)

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x=Variable, y=value)) + 
  geom_boxplot() + geom_jitter(aes(color=Variable2), shape=16)
```

[image]

Comment: Those black dots come from the `geom_boxplot` layer. The default is to draw points for "outliers" that are more than 1.5 times the IQR from the 1st and 3rd quartiles. You can turn them off using the methods in this existing question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5677885/ignore-outliers-in-ggplot2-boxplot

Comment: Thanks, I had never come across something like this until now!

Comment: For future reference, this is what worked for me: "ggplot(df, aes(x=Variable, y=value)) + 
  geom_boxplot(outlier.colour = NA) + geom_jitter(aes(color=Variable2), shape=16) adding the outlier.colour=NA"